# Oracle Apex shuttle: set list of value from PL/SQL process

Tags: javascript, plsql, process, oracle-apex, shuttle

I'm having difficulties trying to set the **LEFT** panel of a **shuttle** with value I calculate in a PL/SQL process.

I can only set the **RIGHT** panel list of value from there.

I've read about `apex.server.process` to call in a JavaScript event, but I can't figure it out. Furthermore, I wonder if there's any simpler way to do so.

My process simply sets a page Item `P1_TMP` to something like :  `'abc:def:ghi'`.

I'd like to set the left panel of the shuttle with the values from `P1_TPM` whenever the process is called.

What I've tried so far (I'm not sure what to pass in the second argument of the function):

```
apex.server.process( "MY_PROCESS", {
        pageItems: "#P1_SOME_ITEM"
    },
    {
        success: function( pData ) {
            $("#P1_MY_SHUTTLE_LEFT").append("<option value=test>test</option>");
    }
}
);
```

I'm under Apex 19.1

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe your business case with a very simple example ? It's hard to see what you are trying to achieve since you're mixing your solution into your question.

Comment: @KoenLostrie To keep simple, I'm trying to set the values of the left panel of a shuttle dynamically.

Comment: "dynamically" - yes you said that, but please give me a very simple example

Comment: @KoenLostrie Ok, so I have a process that calculates the list of values I want to put in my shuttle. When I try to pass it directly to the shuttle with `:P1_MY_SHUTTLE := list_of_values` it populates the right side panel. I'm looking for a way to do so but for the left side panel. What can I say more ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie I reformulated the question > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62550312/how-to-populate-left-side-of-shuttle-in-oracle-apex