# Oracle Apex: refresh item on another item change

Tags: events, refresh, oracle-apex, onchange, items

I'm trying to refresh a `Shuttle` Item whenever a `Select List` item is modified.

What I've done so far:

I have an item `P1_MY_LIST` which is a list of value. And I have a `P1_MY_SHUTTLE` which is populated by this query :

```
SELECT a, b FROM my_table WHERE col1 = :P1_MY_LIST;
```

Then I created a Change event on `P1_MY_LIST` which contain a `TRUE Event` set to Refresh the `P1_MY_SHUTTLE` item.

Yet, nothing happens when I select something in my `P1_MY_LIST` .

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For refreshing a shuttle based on a selected value in a select list, you're better off using the legacy "Cascading List of Values" attribute.

In your case: On page item P1_MY_SHUTTLE, set "Cascading List Of Value" > "Parent Item" to P1_MY_LIST. That should do it.

If for some reason that does not work in your case you can do a dynamic action but there is caveat. There is no option to submit the selected value to the server so your select list will not use the newly selected P1_MY_LIST. As a result it looks as if it is not refreshing, but actually it is.You can work around that by

- adding a true action *before* your refresh action.
- Action: "Execute PL/SQL Code"
- PL/SQL Code  "NULL;" (you don't need to do anything)
- Items to submit "P1_MY_LIST".

That will ensure that P1_MY_LIST gets picked up when the query is executed again and it will show the correct values in your shuttle.

Comment: Items to submit "P1_MY_LIST" -> That did the trick! That's what I was missing. Thanks a lot.