# Dynamic action is not trigger if i will put the LOV select list value in where condition on click button event

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am selecting a value from LoV.Then i am clicking a button to trigger dynamic action(When->event=click,selection type->Button,Button name).Then in Server-side Condition i am putting (rows return->select * from tab)--Its triggering as expected,But if i will change sql query (select * from tab where col=:Lov)(there is 1 record,but its not triggering).

Comment: Does this help ? I think it is similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62634193/oracle-apex-refresh-item-on-another-item-change

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it is not triggered, is because a server-side condition tells APEX whether or not to load the defined Dynamic Action when rendering the page.

In your first example, the query `select * from tab` will return rows. So when rendering the page, the dynamic action will be loaded and executed when the button has been pressed.

In your second example, including the where clause `select * from tab col=:Lov`,  page item `:lov` is most likely still empty when rendering the page and therefore the dynamic action is not being loaded and doesn’t exist for the browser at the moment you press the button.

Server-side condition is not the right solution here.

If you want the dynamic action only being executed when the selected lov item also exist in a table.

- In APEX 5.1 you can execute an AJAX call in your DA to check the row existence before executing the actual logic.
- In APEX 19.2 you can define extra output columns in a LOV, which you can use to set an additional page item. Set that item as an indicator (Y/N) to run the DA. Then you can use the Client-side condition to determine whether or not the DA should be executed, based on the indicator.

Hope this helps. Let me know when you need further assistence with one of the two solutions.