# Refresh Select List

Tags: oracle-apex

I have two Select Lists, first one contains data from database (*names*, *ids*; `P19_FIRST`), second one must contain another list of data (*names*; `P19_SECOND`) by data from first *select list*. I create dynamic action (*change* event) which one must update second *select list* by data from first one, but this does not happens. When I choose element from first *select list*, *dynamic action* must set value with SQL statement for second list (`P19_SECOND`):

```sql
select distinct name d, id r
from function
where function.company_id = :P19_FIRST
order by id
```

If I trying same code for *Display Only* instead of *Select List*, it works, but shows only *names*, without *ids*. By default (*List of Values*) for item `P19_SECOND` query is same and it works correctly (*value* is *id* and *option name* is *name*). What I doing wrong?

Comment: Check out this question. I believe it is the same as yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62634193/oracle-apex-refresh-item-on-another-item-change/62657597#62657597

Comment: @KoenLostrie, thank you very much! I have no idea how I skiped that topic. But now I have another problem. When page is loaded for the first time (not one item was selected, but by default sets first item from the list), second list is doesn't updates, it's empty. I tried create Dynamic Action before refresh action with Execute PL/SQL Code action and NULL code, but it doesn't works for me. How I can update second list?

Comment: Does your dynamic action have "fire on initialization" set to "on" ?

Comment: In any case, the cascading select list is easier than a dyn action. The case you describe does work with a cascading select list.

Comment: @KoenLostrie, no, I forgot about that. I'm tried it now, but it's not a good solution for me, because if I editing data, it's sets first value from the list, but not old one from database. Few minutes ago I finded another solution which one is good for me. I created Dynamic Action on page load. If value from second list is empty, I refresh it (P19_SECOND). Thank you!